# Sign-up button is not working in my Launchrock widget

Tags: javascript, css, widget, launch

I built a landingpage --> http://www.zentify.com/ 
I used twitter bootstrap and integrated the Launchrock widget and adjusted some of the css.
Now it looks like I wanted it to look, but the submit button "Jetzt Unternehmen anmelden" does not work.

Does somebody understand why that button is not leading anywhere? 
Which code snippets would be helpful to see?

Here is my custom css
https://github.com/Boeru/Zentify-website/blob/master/css/custom.css

The CSS and html of the widget I do edit directly in the advanced code editor while logged in into Launchrock widget editor.

This is the JS which comes with the Launchrock Widget (Does the problem lie here?)

```
The widget css in the Launchrock advanced code editor
window.lrignition.themesJS.customTheme = function() {
/* DO NOT MODIFY ABOVE THIS LINE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING */
this.init.push(function() {
    /* Your code here to run on initialization */
});
// Uncomment to override default mode set behavior
/*
this.setMode = function( ignition, mode ) {
    var container = ignition.getContainer(); // jQuery
    if( mode === "main" ) {
        container.find( ".LR-content" ).removeClass( "LR-sharing-page" );
        container.find( ".LR-site-share" ).hide();
        container.find( ".LR-sign-up-container" ).show();
    } else if( mode === "postsignup" ) {
        container.find( ".LR-content" ).addClass( "LR-sharing-page" );
        container.find( ".LR-sign-up-container" ).hide();
        container.find( ".LR-site-share" ).show();
    }
};
*/
/* DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING */
  };
  window.lrignition.themesJS.customTheme.prototype = new ( window.lrignition.themesJS.clean || window.lrignition.themesJS.common )( "customTheme" );
```

This is the overwrite css of the widget

```
.LR-sign-up-submit{

style="background-color:#00FA9A;"
height: 100px;
    }


.myButton {
width: 98%;



    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #00fa9a;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #00fa9a;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #00fa9a;

    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #00fa9a), color-stop(1, #00fa9a));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #00fa9a 5%, #00fa9a 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00fa9a 5%, #00fa9a 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #00fa9a 5%, #00fa9a 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #00fa9a 5%, #00fa9a 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #00fa9a 5%, #00fa9a 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00fa9a', endColorstr='#00fa9a',GradientType=0);

    background-color:#00fa9a;

    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;

    border:1px solid #fafafa;

    display:inline-block;
   color: #333333;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:11px 38.5px  ;
    margin:0px 3px 6px ;
    text-decoration:none;

    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #00fa9a;

}
.myButton:hover {

    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #33FF99), color-stop(1, #33FF99));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #33FF99 5%, #33FF99 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #33FF99 5%, #33FF99 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #33FF99 5%, #33FF99 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #33FF99 5%, #33FF99 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #33FF99 5%, #33FF99 100%);


    background-color:#33FF99;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


.LR-bg-img {
margin-top: 0px;
background-attachment: relative;
background-color: #222222;
background-image: url("img/classicBg.png");
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
content: "";
height: 700px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}


div.LR-box-container {
z-index: -1;
}


.LR-content {
margin-top: 75px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 300;
height: 600px;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative; 
z-index: 0;
display: block;
}

.cookie {
margin-top: 160px;
font-family: Cookie;
font-size: 6em
}


.neuehelvetica {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
margin-top: -40px;}

div#lr-widget {


height: 540px;
```

If there is more code to be posted to understand my problem, please let me know.
Advice and comments greatly appreciated. I guess it is a rather small problem, but personally I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I get errors indicating that none of the linked scripts on your page have loaded.  Of particular interest is that jQuery didn't load, nor any of the bootstrap.js scripts.

Comment: Thanks Ryan to point this problem out. I corrected the js links in my local directory.

The Launchrock guys replied to me that most probably it had something to do with my custom code and that I probably commented something important out. 

I reset default code inside the widget editor and now slowly strip the css again.

Comment: No problem.  If you can get the live site scripts loading, I'd be happy to take a look.